# trigger a function if 'del' is called on a class instance?

Tags: python

I really tried to get my head around this, but I simply can't think of any nice way to di this...  so my question is the following:

Suppose you have an instance of a class, that has some nasty
references (circular references, connected callbacks in a gui)
that prevent it from being garbage-collected,
but you have the possibility to "unreference" the object manually
by calling `x.cleanup()`, e.g.:

```
class asdf:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1    
    
    def __del__():
        # this funciton is called AFTER garbage-collection...
        print("object is destroyed")
        
    def cleanup(self):
        # a function to cleanup all references that would
        # prevent the object from being garbage-collected
        print("object is released")

x = asdf()
```

now if I would call

```
del x
```

the object would still remain "alive", due to the unresolved references...
however, if I do

```
x.cleanup()
del x
```

the object gets garbage-collected just fine.

Now, what I'm searching for is a possibility to automate this process,
but I simply can't find a proper way to execute the cleanup-function if `del` is called on an instance of the class.
Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: The hook you are looking for does not exist. Despite the similarity in names, `del` and `__del__` aren't related; there is no hook that gets called when `del` is used.

Comment: You *probably* want to use a context manager in some way.

Comment: hey, thanks for the comment! I know that a context-manager could solve the problem, but I'm curious as if there's any possibility to do this without using context-managers...

Comment: ... in addition I'm also curious why such a hook does not exist in python?

Comment: `del` is only very rarely used (though whether that was, in the beginning, *why* no hook exists, or *because* no hook exists, I couldn't say).

Comment: Basically, the `with` statement gives you more control over when cleanup is done than relying on all references to a particular object being removed or going out of scope.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarifications so far... seems like I'll be switching to context-managers soon... I'll still keep this question open for a while to see if somebody comes up with a nice idea.. you never know :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn’t well posed: should

```
x=asdf()
y=x
del y
```

trigger it?

You might be able to make some other part of the system use **weak** references to break the cycles.  Of course, since Python 3.4 all cycles have been **collectible** so long as no old-style `tp_del` C extensions are in use, so the issue might be overblown.

Comment: hey, thanks for this comment... you are of course right... I guess what i was searching for is a method to force-delete a class instance despite existing references ... however after spending quite some time on this I realized that this would only open the door for madness in python which is most probably why it doesn't exist :-D  In the end weak references did the job perfectly (at least after getting rid of using `lru_cache` which is not reliable with proxies in python 3.7... but that's maybe already fixed in later versions)